# How do I solve an 'End of statement expected' compiler error for a VB 'If` statement?

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb.net-2010, c#-to-vb.net

I'm not too good in VB.net, mostly working with C#, and I have the following `foreach` loop:

```
Dim pSources() As Integer = {}
pSources = SCCC.GetSources(SysCompany, SysUser, ccHeaderId)

Try

    For Each intSelect As Integer In pSources 

        For Each li As ListItem In chkSources.Items 

            If Convert.ToInt32(li.Value) Equals(intSelect)
                li.Selected = True
            End If

        Next

    Next

Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

I would like to check for each item in the `pSources` array of `Integer`, to find the appropriate value in the list of checkboxes and check the checkbox if the value match.

With the code I have at this moment I'm getting error on the line where I do the if comparison, and this is the error:

> End of statement expected

How can I fix this?

Or maybe better, how I can use a LINQ statement which will check for the value and then check the checkboxes if the value is contained in the `pSources` array?

Comment: you really should look at the formatting of the code and try formatting your for loops nested in the correct way..meaning where are the matching end for statements ..this is visually quite obvious

Comment: Don't you need a `Then` with the `If`, and why have the try/catch in there at all?

Comment: and if you are in a sub where is the end sub..? here is a great tutorial that you can look at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_foreachnext_loops.htm also I would suggest you look at how to format your routines functions etc..

Comment: It would help to explain what some of those object are and post real code.  What is ListItem?  Is this Winforms?  Mysteries abound

Comment: If Convert.ToInt32(li.Value) Equals(intSelect) - thats where I want to know how to compare the checkbox value against the integer variable

Comment: In VB.NET, you can use `=` to check for equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do myself...

The below code checks to make sure `pSources` is something and also has something in it. The `Integer.TryParse` will not throw an exception if it can't parse and will short circuit before trying to do a comparison...

```
 Dim pSources As New List(Of Integer)
 Dim intNumber As Integer = 0
 pSources = SCCC.GetSources(SysCompany, SysUser, ccHeaderId)

 Try
    If pSources IsNot Nothing AndAlso pSources.Count > 0 Then
      For Each intSelect In pSources 
       For Each li As ListItem In chkSources.Items 
        If Integer.TryParse(li.Value.ToString, intNumber) AndAlso (intNumber = intSelect) Then
            li.Selected = True
        End If
       Next
      Next 
    End If

 Catch ex As Exception
  'Handle your exception...
 End Try
```

Comment: I like the one-line syntax of `.TryParse` followed by `AndAlso (predicate)`. Nice construct.

Answer (score 3):

Two problems that I see:

1) Like Russ points out, you need a `Then` statement after `If`. In VB, the syntax is

```
If <boolean statement> Then
    <Some Code>
End If
```

2) I do not see a `.` joining `Equals` in your boolean statement.  This is just invalid syntax.  Like was suggested in the comments, you can use the `=` operator here for more clarity.  If you still want to use `Equals` then add a `.` between `Converter.ToInt32(li.Value)` and `Equals`.  Your final code should be below:

```
Dim pSources() As Integer = {}
pSources = SCCC.GetSources(SysCompany, SysUser, ccHeaderId)

Try

    For Each intSelect As Integer In pSources 

        For Each li As ListItem In chkSources.Items 

            If Convert.ToInt32(li.Value).Equals(intSelect) Then
                li.Selected = True
            End If

        Next

    Next

Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

Comment: `pSources` could be nothing and should be checked before trying to use the object. You don't need to explicitly say  `As Integer` as `pSources` is an array of `Integers` it's not needed as your casting it again when not needed. `Convert.ToInt32` will throw an exception if it's not an `Integer`... just a few suggestions...

Comment: My proposed solution is simply a modification of the asker's original code, not how I would approach it.  Also pSources can't be `Nothing` since it is both intialized with `{}` and also set again the very next line.

Comment: What if the call `SCCC.GetSources(SysCompany, SysUser, ccHeaderId)` returns nothing, kaboom! You can't alway's depend on a function to return something...

Comment: Fair enough, it's still irrelevant as it's not really the point of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your IF statement requires a "THEN" at the end of it.  There are some decent C# to VB.NET conversion applications online (such as this [code converter from Telerik](http://converter.telerik.com/))--you might try some of those to help you gain familiarity with VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
    Dim pSources = SCCC.GetSources(SysCompany, SysUser, ccHeaderId)

    Dim val = 0
    For l = 0 To chkSources.Items.Count - 1
        chkSources.SetSelected(l, Integer.TryParse(chkSources.Items(l).ToString, val) AndAlso pSources.Contains(val))
    Next
```